# change states as well as navigating to another screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a navigation container that calls a function to my stack. I would like to navigate to a tab screen from a stack screen AND change a state in that tab screen. I have given some code below and a demo. In the demo you can see on screen3(stack screen) I am trying to navigate to Home(tab screen) and change a state so that it renders the MapHome screen.

I am unsure how to pass the state to the bottom tab screen without rendering it elsewhere.
I appreciate any insight more than you know.

here is my [demo](https://snack.expo.dev/@priedejm/bottom-stack-page-to-home-while-changing-states) as well as some code below of App.js. You must run the demo in IOS or android, it will not work for web.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

import Home from './Home'
import ListHome from './screens/screen1'
import MapHome from './screens/screen2'
import Screen3 from './screens/screen3'

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function MyTabs() {
  return (

    <Stack.Navigator
     initialRouteName="Home">        
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component= {Home} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
      <Stack.Screen name="Screen1" component= {ListHome} options={{headerShown: false}}/> 
       <Stack.Screen name="Screen2" component= {MapHome} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
    </Stack.Navigator>
);
}


export default function App() {

  return (
   <NavigationContainer>
    <Tab.Navigator
    initialRouteName="Home"
    screenOptions={{
      tabBarActiveTintColor: '#F60081',
      tabBarInactiveTintColor: '#4d4d4d',
      tabBarStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#d1cfcf',
        borderTopColor: 'transparent',
      },
    }} 
  >
    <Tab.Screen
      name="Home"
      component={MyTabs}
      options={{
        tabBarLabel: 'Home',
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
          <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={size} />
        ),
      }}
    />

     <Tab.Screen
      name="Screen3"
      component={Screen3}
      options={{
        tabBarLabel: 'Screen3',
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
          <MaterialCommunityIcons name="account-group" color={color} size={size} />
        ),
      }}
    />
    
  </Tab.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
);
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
```

Comment: Have you tried navigating with parameters?

Comment: Could you provide an example from an online article or a link to some documentation? I am not quite sure I understand exactly what you mean.

Comment: Demo isn't working for me, `Unable to fetch module snackager-1/react-native-maps`

Comment: @Spankied You must run it on IOS or android, it wont work for web

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a parameter from `Screen3` to the `Home` screen.

I have forked your demo and did some small refactoring (including changing from Class to Function components just for preference) so you may need to adapt it to your needs. You can find it [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@hannigan/bottom-stack-page-to-home-while-changing-states).

In `Screen3` you can modify your onPress logic to the following:

```js
navigation.navigate('Home', {
  screen: 'Home',
    params: {
      componentToShow: 'Screen2'
    }
});
```

Here's a breakdown of why you are seeing `Home` twice:

```js
navigation.navigate('Home', {       // <-- Tab.Screen name. 
  screen: 'Home',                   // <-- Stack.Screen name.
    params: {
      componentToShow: 'Screen2'
    }
});
```

With this code you are now passing a `route.param` to the Home screen. I've included a `useEffect` to run any time `route.params` changes.

```js
const [whichComponentToShow, setComponentToShow] = React.useState("Screen1");

React.useEffect(() => {
  if(route.params && route.params.componentToShow) {
    setComponentToShow(route.params.componentToShow);
  }
}, [route.params]);
```

Now, whenever a User navigates to the `Home` screen and a `componentToShow` route parameter is provided, the Home screen will update.

Comment: Thank you for this insight. Exactly what I needed.

Comment: Do you have any ideas as to how I could go about updating that slider button as well? No worries if not as I know that was not apart of the question. I have been thinking about it today but have not come up with any solutions.